# R download svg file from webpage

Tags: r, svg, web-scraping

From https://stooq.pl/q/?s=%5Espx&d=20181016&c=1d&t=l&a=lg&b=0

I would like to download main image with SP500 index, its img tag is :

```
<img src="c/?s=^spx&d=20181016&c=1d&t=l&a=lg" width="560" height="350" border="0">
```

so URL of SVG image alone is : [https://stooq.pl/c/s=^spx&d=20181016&c=1d&t=l&a=lg](https://stooq.pl/c/?s=%5Espx&d=20181016&c=1d&t=l&a=lg)

but R command :

```
download.file("https://stooq.pl/c/?s=^spx&d=20181016&c=1d&t=l&a=lg", "sp500.svg") # or .png
```

downloads file which is not rendered, is is possible to download proper file ?

Comment: Why do you think that this is `svg`? It seem to be simple PNG image which can be downloaded in the same format as it appears [here](https://stooq.pl/c/s=^spx&d=20181016&c=1d&t=l&a=lg) .

Comment: @Andersson because download.file("https://stooq.pl/c/?s=^spx&d=20181016&c=1d&t=l&a=lg", "sp500.png")  creates png file which cannot be opened

Comment: I have a little experience in R, but I simply got target `png` file in Python without any problems

Comment: @Andersson could you share your code as an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

As been discussed in comments, here is the *Python* code to download required image  ([requests lib](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) is required, but you can use any library that allows to make HTTP-requests):

```
import requests

with open('/path/to/sp500.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(requests.get('https://stooq.pl/c/?s=%5Espx&d=20181016&c=1d&t=l&a=lg').content)
```